# Spring Security two authenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Ok guys I solved a problem of redirecting. But now I have another problem. My web application have three projects. One projects is the home page and tell you if you have permissions to enter to the projects. Everything is ok in that part. But now in the other two projects I have my springsecurity.xml. And have the own logging pages. But now the client told me that want that loging pages and redirect me to the home page the first project. The problem is here.

```
<beans:bean id="casAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter" >
<beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
<!-- Propiedad añadida para el redireccionamiento a AMS1.1 -->       
<beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="http://192.168.1.32:8080/AMS1.1/"/>
      <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

Whenever I entry to the home page I need two click two times. One because There always redirecting because I set

> name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" to true.

That's because whenever I enter to the loging page to the project 2 always redirect me to the project 1. And the project's enter with one click. But whenever I loging with project 1. I need to click to times in the link, button or whatever to enter the project 2.

Now my question is if I can have two "authenticationSuccessHandler". That redirect me to project 2. And clicking once or some logic or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after reading and searching for an answer. I finally found one. So here it goes. I made my own class for Authentication.

```
 <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:bean class="com.ams.dcs.jsf.extras.SuccesHandler">
    </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

And my class

```
public class SuccesHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1, Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
    Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(a.getAuthorities());
    int cont=0;

    String url = hsr.getRequestURL().toString();
    // String para ver si ya estamos adentro de la aplicacion o no
    String ams="http://192.168.1.32:8080/AMS1.1/";
    String referrer = hsr.getHeader("referer");
            //Vemos si tenemos el rol de USER y DCS 
     if(roles.contains("SETT_USER") && roles.contains("DCS_USER") )
    {
    // para el debugeo
    // System.out.print("holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaA:"+url);
    // System.out.print("holaaaaaaaaaasdfasdfaaaaaaaaaaaA:"+referrer);
     //Si estamos ya logueados   
     if(ams.equals(referrer))
     {
          hsr1.sendRedirect("/DCS?faces-redirect=true");// Si ya estamos logueados que nos redireccione a DCS
     }
     else
              hsr1.sendRedirect("/AMS1.1"); // Sino Que nos redireccione al homepage y de ahy al logging
    }
    else  if(roles.contains("DCS_USER") && roles.contains("SETT_USER"))
    {
         hsr1.sendRedirect("/DCS?faces-redirect=true");
    }

    System.out.print("MIS ROLEEEES"+roles.toString());
}
```

}

I happy that I made it.